# is there any way to see what the differences between two page layouts in terms of contents(fields,related list,components etc.)

Tags: apex, page-layout, standard-objects

how to see  what the differences are between two page layouts

I just want to see which fields are displayed on one page vs another.  This could work like a text comparison feature.

For exmple:

**Layout 1**
*Field 1
Field 3*

**Layou 2**
*Field 1
Field 4
vf page*.

Please suggest.

Comment: upvote for this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Jsfp you might get this in future.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the exact UI feature in salesforce that you are looking for. But you could compare the two metadata files in eclipse. This would give you a fairly good idea about the differences between the page layouts. In eclipse

1. Select both the page layouts files, using Ctrl for multiselect, on the left pane.
2. Right click any of the selected and choose 'Compare With' --> 'Each Other'.

This would show a satisfactory comparison between the metadata of both the files. It is possible to understand the fields and their relative ordering differences. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ajay This can be done easily. You can also use an online difference checker  to check file differences if you have the metdata(.xml) files for page layouts.